# How to write Javascript to search nodes - without getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm very new at recursion, and have been tasked with writing getElementsByClassName in JavaScript without libraries or the DOM API.

There are two matching classes, one of which is in the body tag itself, the other is in a p tag.

The code I wrote isn't working, and there must be a better way to do this. Your insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
var elemByClass = function(className) {
    var result = [];
    var nodes = document.body; //<body> is a node w/className, it needs to check itself.
    var childNodes = document.body.childNodes; //then there's a <p>  w/className

    var goFetchClass = function(nodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= nodes; i++) { // check the parent
            if (nodes.classList == className) {
                result.push(i);
                console.log(result);
            }
            for (var j = 0; j <= childNodes; j++) { // check the children
                if (childNodes.classList == className) {
                    result.push(j);
                    console.log(result);
                }
                goFetchClass(nodes); // recursion for childNodes
            }
            goFetchClass(nodes); // recursion for nodes (body)
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors, mostly logical, in your code, here's what it should have looked like

```
var elemByClass = function(className) {
    var result  = [];
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");

    (function goFetchClass(nodes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if ( pattern.test(nodes[i].className) ) {
                result.push(nodes[i]);
            }
            goFetchClass(nodes[i].children);
        }
    })([document.body]);

    return result;
};
```

Note the use of a regex instead of `classList`, as it makes no sense to use `classList` which is IE10+ to polyfill `getElementsByClassName`

Firstly, you'd start with the body, and check it's `className` property.
Then you'd get the `children`, not the `childNodes` as the latter includes text-nodes and comments, which can't have classes.
To recursively call the function, you'd pass the children in, and do the same with them, check for a class, get the children of the children, and call the function again, until there are no more children.

Comment: Can I ask you why, if I tried to substitute [document.body] for a variable, it breaks the code? And what the RegExp is doing (sorry that's new to me, but looks like a lot of fun/very useful).

Comment: You could replace `document.body` with another element, but it has to be inside the brackets as the `for` loop expects an array, or array-like object, that has length, not a single element. The regular expression just looks for the given class in the `className` property, which could contain multiple classes, so the regex looks for the class either at the start, the end, or with a space in either end etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reasons:

1. `goFetchClass` needs an initial call after you've defined it - for example, you need a `return goFetchClass(nodes)` statement at the end of `elemByClass` function
2. the line `for (var i = 0; i <= nodes; i++) {` will not enter the for loop - did you mean `i <= nodes.length` ?
3. `nodes.classList` will return an array of classNames, so a direct equality such as `nodes.classList == className` will not work. A `contains` method is better.
4. Lastly, you may want to reconsider having 2 for loops for the parent and children. Why not have 1 for loop and then call `goFetchClass` on the children? such as, `goFetchClass(nodes[i])`?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Michelle, for point #4 especially. I'm afraid though, when I tried to implement it, I couldn't get it working. (Assuming user error since I'm struggling w/ this concept).